# Field not available for report filter?

Tags: reporting

1. I have a custom object(cust_obj__c) and a custom field on this
   object(Field1__c).
2. The custom field(Field1__c) on the object was
       created recently and the object was created long ago.

I want to create a report on this object with the filter condition on the new field created but the new field is not available in the report filter condition when I am trying to select.

What is wrong with this process?

Comment: Did you check the FLS for the field, does it say visible for the profile? FLS restricts the users access to view field in reports https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_fls.htm

Comment: @Rao I figured this out. I had to go to the report types under setup and add that custom field. Now it is working fine.